# Strange behavior with type matching using generic closures

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I get the following error with this Swift code in an Xcode 7.3 Playground.

**Code**

```
/**  
 *  Represents a future value of type U, from a computation that has not been done yet.  
 */ 
public struct Promise<T, U> {
    var futureValue: T -> U

    public func then<T,U,V>(closure: U -> V) -> Promise<T, V> {
        return Promise<T, V>(futureValue: {
            input in
            let value = futureValue(input)
            return closure(value)
        })
    } 
}
```

**Error**

```
error: cannot invoke value of type 'T -> U' with argument list '((T))'
        let value = futureValue(input)
```

This looks like it should work, because the types match up in my definition. What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
public func then<T,U,V>(closure: U -> V) -> Promise<T, V> { ... }
```

the  local generic placeholders `T, U` *hide* (or *shadow*) the
generic placeholders from the

```
public struct Promise<T, U> { ... }
```

type definition. Your method definition is equivalent to

```
public func then<T1,U1,V>(closure: U1 -> V) -> Promise<T1, V> {
    return Promise<T1, V>(futureValue: {
        input in
        let value = futureValue(input)
        return closure(value)
    })
}
```

which then shows the more understandable error message

```
error: cannot invoke value of type 'T -> U' with argument list '((T1))'
```

The solution is simple: Just omit `T` and `U` from the generic placeholder
list in the method definition, these are inherited automatically from
`struct Promise`. Note also that the `futureValue` property must
be referenced via `self` inside the closure:

```
public func then<V>(closure: U -> V) -> Promise<T, V> {
    return Promise<T, V>(futureValue: {
        input in
        let value = self.futureValue(input)
        return closure(value)
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I never knew that templates/generics worked like this! Thanks a ton!